# Case sensitivity file names - Blender on Linux and Windows

Tags: linux

What is the best way to use Windows Blender files on Linux?

I have .blend files created on Windows which is case insensitive.

When I open file with path to Image.jpg and file name is image.jpg it works on Windows well, but on Linux links are broken.

Comment: Does *File > External Data > Find Missing Files* solve the problem for you?

Comment: @Robert Gützkow 
No. 
Linux is case sensitive. Find Missing Files it will not replace missing "Image.jpg" with "image.jpg" automatically.
When my blend file uses many linked libraries and assets. I have to edit each one and find missing textures. It takes time.

Comment: I'm aware, I just didn't have time to check whether the implementation of *Find Missing Files* tries to solve this. Is there some sort of naming convention applied, e.g. all filename are lowercase?